# Set Command property of CommandBinding using internal namespace with custom commands?

Tags: wpf

I'm exploring WPF and seeing if I can work my way to using a full MVVM approach. For now, I think I need to learn how to reference my own custom objects/commands that I've defined in a nearby namespace.

This is my folder structure:
[image]

This is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Commands"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding 
     Command="commands:WordSearchCommand"
     CanExecute="CanExecuteChanged"/>
  </Window.CommandBindings>

  <Grid>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Target="{Binding ElementName=wordSearchBox}">Word _Search:</Label>
      <TextBox 
          Name="wordSearchBox" 
          Height="25" 
          Width="600" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
          Text="{Binding Path=SearchWord}">
      </TextBox>
      <Button Height="25" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding Path=WordSearchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SearchWord}">Search</Button>
    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>

</Window>
```

This is my `MainWindow` code-behind:

```
using AppLogicCommandsAndQueries;
using System.Windows;
using WpfApp1.ViewModels;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new WordSearchViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `WordSearchCommand` definition:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1.Commands
{
    public class WordSearchCommand : ICommand
    {

        private string previousSearch;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate (object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("word search can execute changed");
        };

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return previousSearch != (string)parameter;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            // if online check online db else check offline db

            MessageBox.Show("word search command");

            previousSearch = (string)parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried rebuilding, switching CPU targets, switching to Release mode and back, etc. There's got to be a coding error, right?

This is the error displayed in my build output:

```
WpfApp1\MainWindow.xaml(14,134,14,151): error CS1061: 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'CanExecuteChanged' and no accessible extension method 'CanExecuteChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: I just pushed to a new git repository where one should be able to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/gordlonious/WpfApp1

Comment: Your command binding in MainWindow.xaml references an event handler that does not exist: `<CommandBinding 
     Command="commands:WordSearchCommand"
     CanExecute="CanExecuteChanged"/>`. You need to define it. Rebuilding the project won't write the method for you. That's your job. The other error there is that "commands:WordSearchCommand" is a string, not a command.

Comment: You should look into some kind of DelegateCommand or RelayCommand class. You can find implementations on google. But anyway there's no reason for that CommandBinding to exist at all. Your button binds to the WordSearchCOmmand property of your viewmodel, and from what I can see that's all you need. I can't run your project because of missing dependencies.

Comment: I cloned into a new local repository and reproduced the issue just fine. You need .NET Framework 4.8 installed. Thanks for taking a look but I'm not sure you understand the problem. I know what the error is saying. `MainWindow` does not have a `CanExecuteChanged` event on it. However, `WordSearchCommand` does! How can I make these XAML nodes reference that instead?

Comment: When I run the program the `CanExecute` method never gets called, so it never enables the search button... that's what I'm trying to fix. Sure, I could just comment out `return previousSearch != (string)parameter;`, but then I'd never be able to evaluate the command execution. I was hoping to do it without a `RelayCommand` for now. But if you didn't notice, I have a `RelayCommand` file in the repository already (it's just not being used at the moment).

Comment: I agree with Ed. Command bindings like you have there are rare in commercial apps. I would remove the commandbinding and bind direct from the button to a relaycommand in the viewmodel. Or a static command if this can somehow be a generic thing that'll be re-used elsewhere.

Comment: Are you saying that, without the CommandBinding (which two very experienced WPF guys are telling you you **do not need**; it would be used if you were binding MainWindow event handlers, which you don't have, to a RoutedCommand, which don't have and don't want), WordSearchCommand.CanExecute never gets called? You put in a breakpoint? The Button will handle CanExecuteChanged. It's your job to raise the event when the return value of CanExecute is likely to have changed, so the Button will know to call it again.

Comment: I got the behavior I was looking for. Thanks for steering me away from the CommandBinding in XAML; that was definitely a bad rabbit hole. I think the problem may have stemmed from a misunderstanding of events, namely, the role of `CanExecuteChnaged` on a Command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I don't understand C# events or WPF event routing very well. I was able to get the desired behavior by changing the `CanExecuteChanged` event handler on my `WordSearchCommand`.

Before I had:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate (object s, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("word search can execute changed");
};
```

Which would never execute (I never saw the message box). Also, the `CanExecute` method would only get called once.

Now, I have:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

and now my `CanExecute` method gets called a ton (a bunch at the beginning, and basically anytime I interact with the Window?).

I tried adding event accessors before but didn't realize I needed to remove the delegate signature for the accessor definitions to become syntactically valid. I definitely took inspiration from a `RelayCommand` definition as well as other posts on StackOverflow. I'm still not exactly sure what's going on here, but I've stumbled upon a solution that I can use for now.

Comment: I won't set this 'answer' as accepted since, well, my question wasn't very well worded. I thought the problem was with the command binding.. but I guess the problem was the command's implementation.